# Forcing YouTube quality change without rebuffering, without user input

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-dl

For a specific experiment I need to control YouTube quality changes according to a prewritten scenario, with no user control over quality. Currently, I am doing it via an extension with a function:

```
 setPlaybackQualityRange(targetRes,targetRes)
```

The problem is that despite having a very fast Internet connection, switching from for example 360p to 1080p causes rebuffering. Also, forcing other qualities causes the smallest bufferable chunk to be rebuffered in new quality and as a result a tiny portion of the video gets played again.
**I want to achieve almost immediate change in quality with no rebuffering events**: is it even possible? I was looking into how videos are divided into chunks and is it possible to request a new chunk of higher quality at some point in time, while still playing out the old chunk? Would intercepting .mpd file help somehow?

Comment: Try remembering the old position, then restore it after switching quality.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thank you for this hint, but what function should I use then to restore old position? I am using ` getCurrentTime() ` function to get the old position and ` seekTo(old_position) ` to restore after switching quality and it doesn't seem to be working better.

Comment: `currentTime` on the `video` element.

Comment: Ok, thank you, it helped to prevent playing out the content again. Yet still the rebuffering problem when switching between qualities persists, so if anyone knows how to approach this I would be grateful